# How do I fetch all the data or just the size of it in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The [current documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/databases/) only shows how to list databases but not to fetch all rows and the size of it. How do I fetch databases' size and count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways:

- the best one: `CALL apoc.meta.stats yield nodeCount, relCount`
- not so optimial: `match(p) return p;`

The second one should only be used if you were to get the *feel* of the data, while the first one is what shows the count.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://neo4j.com/blog/data-profiling-holistic-view-neo4j/) is a good blog about data profiling of a neo4j database: https://neo4j.com/blog/data-profiling-holistic-view-neo4j/

You can get the total number of nodes and edges and sizes. Thanks.

Comment: But what is the command to use? I am using `CALL apoc.meta.stats yield nodeCount, relCount`.